# SQL Server - pulling results only by 256 records at a time

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database; I write a simple `SELECT *` query for one table and it takes too long to retrieve the results. Earlier, this process took no time at all.

Something I noticed is that the query results pane populated by 256 records each only. See snapshot of having select * from a table having just 1690 rows.

[image]

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: That doesn't look like SSMS to me. Just to double check, are you *really* using SQL Server? Considering your question seems to be related to the application you're using (you're saying that the application isn't displaying all the record), it would be worth telling us what it is you're using.

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL Server Management Studio (2005).

Comment: Are you sure you're not using Access?  :)

Comment: I suppose my next question is; why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server? Also, if you're saying the query was "fast" before and isn't now, then, most likely, something has changed on the server.

Comment: @Larnu: why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?: It is actually the production server, this is an old system.

Comment: SSMS has two ways to view table contents - select view (read-only), and edit view (where you can in-place edit the contents of rows.) Are you sure you weren't doing a select only the first time? Your screenshot above looks like the edit view, which is a lot slower, and transparently pages results.